# Catkin make a code using qt resource file

Tags: qt, resources, ros

I am working on a project in which I use Qt designer to create an interface to control a robot. In this interface I would like to put a picture. To do that I would like to use the resource way, using a .qrc file. I have created the .rqc file but when I catkin_make my package it doesn't work, the imahe does not appear.

So I have searched a long time to find information but there is nothing clear anywhere. I supposed that I must make changes in my CMakeLists.txt file but I don't know exactly what.

I have find other questions with similar problem but with no answer of what it is needed to add to the CMakeList.txt to make it work.

I am on ubuntu 14.04 and use Qt4.8.6

This is how my files (the ones that interest us) are organised like following:

mypkg
 --CMakeLists.txt
 -resource/
 --resource.qrc
 --images/
 ---picture.jpg
 -include/
 -src/

This is my CMakeLists.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(rqt_mypkg)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  rospy
  roscpp
  roslint
  rqt_gui
  rqt_gui_cpp
  rqt_gui_py
  std_msgs
  genmsg
  message_generation
)

 find_package(Qt4 COMPONENTS QtCore QtGUi REQUIRED)

include(${QT_USE_FILE})

 catkin_python_setup()

roslint_cpp()

catkin_package(
  LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME}
  CATKIN_DEPENDS rospy rqt_gui rqt_gui_cpp rqt_gui_py
)

set (rqt_mypkg_SRCS
//myfiles
)

set(rqt_mypkg_HDRS
  //myfiles
)

set(rqt_mypkg_UIS
//myfiles
)

set(rqt_mypkg_RESOURCES resource/resource.qrc)

qt4_wrap_cpp(rqt_mypkg_MOCS ${rqt_mypkg_HDRS})
qt4_wrap_ui(rqt_mypkg_UIS_H ${rqt_mypkg_UIS})
qt4_add_RESOURCES(rqt_mypkg_RESOURCES_RCC ${rqt_mypkg_RESOURCES})

include_directories(
include
${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/..
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}
    ${rqt_mypkg_SRCS}
    ${rqt_mypkg_MOCS}
   ${rqt_mypkg_UIS_H}
   ${rqt_mypkg_RESOURCES_RCC}
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
  ${QT_QTCORE_LIBRARY}
${QT_QTGUI_LIBRARY}
${QT4_LIBRARIES}
 )

add_executable(receveur src/rqt_mypkg/receveur.cpp)
target_link_libraries(receveur ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(receveur rqt_mypkg_generate_messages_cpp)

add_executable(gait_generation src/snake_control/gait_generation.cpp)
target_link_libraries(gait_generation ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(gait_generation snake_control_generate_messages_cpp)

qt4_add_resources(resSources resource/resource.qrc)
add_executable(... ${resSources}) 

install(FILES plugin.xml
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
)

install(PROGRAMS scripts/rqt_mypkg
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)
```

Comment: You resource `resSources` isn't linked to any target. Is that the one containing your image? What does the line `add_executable(... ${resSources})` stand for?

Comment: I don't know, I put this line because I found someone in a forum who said to put it that but I don't know what it does.

Comment: If you don't know what it does, remove it :) If it was useful, you will know it. If it's not, you will know it too. What about the other question? Is `resSources` the resource containing your image? What is the target (library or executable) using this resource?